# Print numbers in order with random delay without modifying setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

```
function getNum(value, callback){

    setTimeout(()=> {
        callback(value)
    }, Math.random()*1000)
}

 function getNumList(arr, callback){
    //complete this function
    //use the given "getNum" function
    //(not allowed to use Math.sqrt function)
    //(not allowed to use setTimeout function)
   for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
   getNum(arr[i],callback)
 }

getNumList([1,3,2,4,6,5,7,9,8,10], (nums)=> console.log(nums))
//should print [1,3,2,4,6,5,7,9,8,10] in console
```

How to solve this question by modifying only getNumList? For recursion or promises, I will have to modify the getNum function according to my understanding. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Should it print `[1,3,2,4,6,5,7,9,8,10]` in the console, or every number separately as your function currently does?

Comment: Yeah, seperately is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the call to `getRoot` with a promise and pass `_ => res(callback(_))` as the callback to `getRoot`

```js
function getRoot(value, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const root = Math.sqrt(value)
    callback(root)
  }, Math.random() * 1000)
}

async function getRootList(arr, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    await new Promise((res) =>
      getRoot(arr[i], (...args) => res(callback(...args)))
    )
  }
}

getRootList([1, 9, 4, 16, 36, 25, 49, 81, 64, 100], (roots) => console.log(roots))
```

Note:

- `(...args)` part is not required in your case. But, in case the callback is has multiple arguments that's required.
- Passing callback value to `res` is useful if the `console.log` wasn't part of the callback. This way, you can get the values returned by the callback inside the loop. Here's an example where the callback has the logic:

```js
function getRoot(value, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, Math.random() * 1000, value)
}

async function getRootList(arr, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   const value = await new Promise((res) =>
        getRoot(arr[i], (...args) => res(callback(...args)))
      )
    console.log(value)
  }
}

getRootList([1, 9, 4, 16, 36, 25, 49, 81, 64, 100], Math.sqrt)
// getRootList([1, 9, 4, 16, 36, 25, 49, 81, 64, 100], (a, pow = 2) => Math.pow(a, pow))
```

Comment: I like this solution. Im curious how you came up with the solution? Have you done a similar question before?

Comment: @Guineaguinea it's basic asynchronous programming. There is *quite a lot* of this in JS. In a way, there is nothing new under the sun - it's just turning the callback to a promise, then working with the promise. It's not a special approach for exactly this question and this question only. You can apply it to any async code which uses callbacks.

Comment: @VLAZ I want to solve more questions like this. Where do you think I can find these questions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's the end goal here. There are many approaches, but non of them makes complete sense (as the end callback receives `roots` prop). If it's about exercising recursion, then this would help:

```js
// not modified
function getRoot(value, callback){
    setTimeout(()=> {
        const root = Math.sqrt(value)
        callback(root)
    }, Math.random()*1000)
    // console.log()
}

 function getRootList(arr, callback){
    if (!arr.length) { // a way to stop the recursion
        return;
    }
    getRoot(arr[0], (rt) => { // get the root for the first element of the array
      callback(rt); // print it
      getRootList(arr.slice(1), callback); // start recursion, stripping the 1st element
    });
 }

getRootList([1,9,4,16,36,25,49,81,64,100], (roots)=> console.log(roots))
//should print [1,3,2,4,6,5,7,9,8,10] in console
```